# Getting Strange errors from Server - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I try to run this simple line of code on one of our Print Servers it fails, but it works fine on the other Server.

```
get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Printer -ComputerName "PRINT-SERVER" | Select-Object Name, Direct >>C:\Temp\Printer-Direct.txt
```

I get the following:

At line:1 char:1

- get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Printer -ComputerName "PRINT-SERVER" | S ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
  ```

Any ideas?

BTW - the name is correct, the server responds to Test-NetConnection and my brain is in a fog today thanks to Daylight Saving.

Comment: Have you tried a good old fashioned reboot? Or WMI diagnostic tools? This comes up when I google your exception....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902141/get-wmiobject-returns-an-error-without-a-description

Comment: I just did and it seemed to have resolved the error problem. 
Trying to again and see if I get my other script to run. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't with PowerShell or anything to do with the code.  The error I was getting was a direct issue with the Print Server.

I didn't do any diagnostics since rebooting the server solved the problem.  If the issue appears again, I may have to run the WMI Diagnostic tools to find out what is the problem, but I suspect it might have been a pending update on the Server due to Security updates.

Thank you to AussieJoe for the tip.